# My puppeteer won't click the size button that I want on zalando, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, puppeteer, checkout

[image: 1]

Im using puppeteer to create a sneakerbot and everything has been going good until i wanted it to choose what shoesize i desired. When it didn't work. I did the exact same thing as all the other times. I used the command:

```
enter code here

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const product_url = "https://www.zalando.se/jordan-air-1-mid-hoega-
```

sneakers-armory-navywhiteblack-joc12n001-k12.html"

```
async function givePage(){
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
const page = await browser.newPage();
return page;
}

async function addToCart(page){
await page.goto(product_url)   
await page.waitForSelector("button[class='uc-btn uc-btn-primary']");
await page.click("button[class='uc-btn uc-btn-primary']", elem => 
elem.click());
await page.waitForSelector("button[class='DJxzzA u9KIT8 uEg2FS U_OhzR 
ZkIJC- Vn-7c- FCIprz heWLCX JIgPn9 LyRfpJ pxpHHp Md_Vex NN8L-8 GTG2H9 
MfX1a0 WCjo-q EKabf7 aX2-iv r9BRio mo6ZnF  PLvOOB']");
await page.click("button[class='DJxzzA u9KIT8 uEg2FS U_OhzR ZkIJC- 
Vn-7c- FCIprz heWLCX JIgPn9 LyRfpJ pxpHHp Md_Vex NN8L-8 GTG2H9 MfX1a0 
WCjo-q EKabf7 aX2-iv r9BRio mo6ZnF  PLvOOB']", elem => elem.click());
await page.waitForSelector("button[class='J1Rmt- _6-WsK3 Md_Vex 
Nk_Omi _MmCDa _0xLoFW FCIprz NN8L-8 _7Cm1F9 FxZV-M ovwSlD LyRfpJ 
K82if3 heWLCX mo6ZnF pVrzNP']");
await page.click("button[class='J1Rmt- _6-WsK3 Md_Vex Nk_Omi _MmCDa 
_0xLoFW FCIprz NN8L-8 _7Cm1F9 FxZV-M ovwSlD LyRfpJ K82if3 heWLCX 
mo6ZnF pVrzNP']", elem => elem.click());
}

async function checkout(){
var page = await givePage();
await addToCart(page);
}

checkout();
```

I was expecting that it would choose the desired shoesize but it didn't at first i thougt that the problem was that it couldn't choose it because it couldn't render it in because you hade to scroll down for the size EU 49 but then I tried to set it to headless true so it wouldn't have to see it. After that didn't work I tried a shoesize that you could see immediatelty the shoesize and so it could pick. That didn't work either. So what to do now???

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out how to solve this i usually do the code

```js
await page.selector("button=class'']");
await page.click("button=class'']");
```

Now i did this:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName('')[0].click());
```

And that was the answer to my question. It depends for every computer which command is needed because if it's slow it can have trouble with using my first command and the second might work better.